# How to split JSON into 2 arrays and before I pass it to getJSON for later manipulation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json data and i am  trying to split it into 2 sets of data arrays One json data will hold all the values from "Construct" data values and the 2nd json data will hold the rest of the array and values for product,system etc etc.

I want to split it into 2 arrays  before i pass it into getJSON . Once I split them into 2 then pass the  restofJSONdata into getJSON vice versa

How can I  split them into 2 arrays before i pass it to getJSON?
MY current code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () // don't do anything until the document is loaded.
   {

           var baseUrl = "config.json";

           console.log(baseUrl.html.splice(3)); // remove and log the empty fieldset
                var constructgrp = baseUrl.html.shift(); // remove the first item (caption: "Construct")

                var restofJSONdata = baseUrl.html; 
               alert(constructgrp);


           $.getJSON(restofJSONdata, function (data) // call getJSON providing the complete url with search term and a JSONP callback
           {
               // console.log(data.html.splice(2,3));
              // console.log("data " +data);
              /*
               console.log(data.html.splice(3,0)); // remove and log the empty fieldset
                var constructgrp = data.html.shift(); // remove the first item (caption: "Construct")

                var restofJSONdata = data.html; 
               alert(constructgrp); :*/

               $("#demo-3-form").empty(); // clear out any previous results.
               if (data.html.length < 1) $('#demo-3-forms').html("No results. Nada. Nuttin. Zippo.");

               //$("#demo-3-form").empty(); // clear out any previous results.
              // if (data.html.length < 1) $('#demo-3-forms').html("No results. Nada. Nuttin. Zippo.");
            //   $.each(this.constructgrp, function () // iterate over the results, constructing the HTML for the display.
              // {
                /*
                     var html =constructgrp.type +' :';
                     html += '<b>'+constructgrp.caption +'</b><br>';

                     html += ' <br>';
                       $.each(constructgrp.html, function() {
                         //  alert(this.name);
                          html +='Title :' +this.title +'<br>';
                           html +='Name :' +this.name +'<br>';
                           html +='Value :' +this.value +'<br> ';
                           html +='Caption :' +this.caption +'<br><br> ';
                          // html += this.type +'<br><br> ';
                       });  
                   $('#demo-3-form').hide().append(html).fadeIn(800); // fade in the results over 2 seconds.
                   */
              // });



                $.each(restofJSONdata, function () // iterate over the results, constructing the HTML for the display.
               {

                     var html =this.type +' :';
                     html += '<b>'+this.caption +'</b><br>';

                     html += ' <br>';
                       $.each(this.html, function() {
                         //  alert(this.name);
                          html +='Title :' +this.title +'<br>';
                           html +='Name :' +this.name +'<br>';
                           html +='Value :' +this.value +'<br> ';
                           html +='Caption :' +this.caption +'<br><br> ';
                          // html += this.type +'<br><br> ';
                       });  
                   $('#demo-3-form').hide().append(html).fadeIn(800); // fade in the results over 2 seconds.
               });


           });
       //});
   });




    </script>
```

JSON code
config.json

```
{
    "html": [{
        "type": "fieldset",
        "caption": "Construct",
        "html": [{
            "title": "tooltip data for rk",
            "name": "rk_",
            "value": "24",
            "caption": "DNS Servers (a list of IP addresses separated by comas)",
            "type": "textarea"
        }, {
            "title": "tooltip data for rk_ntpservers",
            "name": "rk_ntpservers",
            "value": "111.11.11.11",
            "caption": " separated by comas",
            "type": "textarea"
        }, {
            "title": "tooltip data for ff_eth0_ff",
            "name": "ff_eth0_ff",
            "value": "18",
            "caption": "Public  Address (0.0.0.0 to disable)",
            "type": "text"
        }, {
            "title": "tooltip data for ff_eth0_netmask",
            "name": "ff_eth0_netmask",
            "value": "2.2.2.0",
            "caption": "Public rk Netmask",
            "type": "text"
        }, {
            "title": "tooltip data for ff_eth1_ff",
            "name": "ff_eth1_ff",
            "value": "0.0.0.0",
            "caption": "MG Device rk (0.0.0.0 to disable)",
            "type": "text"
        }, {
            "title": "tooltip data for ff_eth1_netmask",
            "name": "ff_eth1_netmask",
            "value": "2.2.2.0",
            "caption": "MG Device rk Netmask",
            "type": "text"
        }, {
            "title": "tooltip data for ff",
            "name": "ff_gateway",
            "value": "1",
            "caption": "Gateway",
            "type": "text"
        }]
    }, {
        "type": "fieldset",
        "caption": "Product",
        "html": [{
            "title": "tooltip data for product_ident",
            "name": "product_ident",
            "value": "78",
            "caption": "Product Name",
            "type": "text",
            "disabled": "disabled"
        }, {
            "title": "tooltip data for product_svnversion",
            "name": "product_svnversion",
            "value": "7916",
            "caption": "Revision",
            "type": "text",
            "disabled": "disabled"
        }]
    }, {
        "type": "fieldset",
        "caption": "System ",
        "html": [{
            "title": "tooltip data for system_license",
            "name": "system_license",
            "value": "HH",
            "caption": "License",
            "type": "text"
        }, {
            "title": "tooltip data for system_variant",
            "name": "system_variant",
            "value": "normal",
            "caption": "Variant",
            "type": "text"
        }]
    }, {
        "type": "fieldset",
        "class": "btn-fieldset",
        "caption": "",
        "html": [{
            "type": "submit",
            "id": "submitbtn",
            "class": "btn btn-primary",
            "value": "Save"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: "*split before i pass it into getJSON and then pass `restofJSONdata` into getJSON*" - Huh, what? Do you want to load two different files? What is `baseUrl.html` supposed to be?

Comment: by BaseUrl.html I was trying to split the Json  into  two arrays and then pass it into getJSON. one for Construct and the rest for to store in restofJSONdata as test platform. Ultimately,I want to split them so I can better manipulate and I need to split it before i pass into jquery.dform http://daffl.github.com/jquery.dform/.     and I only want to pass the restofJSONdata except Construct into          $('#myform').dform('config.json', function(data) { 
this // -> generated form

console.log(data.html.splice(1));
//console.log( data);

});

Comment: If you want @Bergi to respond you need to use mention like this. Only post author get notification.

Comment: @user244394: No, it does not work that way. `baseUrl` is just a simple plain ***string***, and has no `html` property.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, so he needs to fetch JSON first as I described below. Then in the first part is in `construct` and all remanning in the `data.html`

Answer (score 0):

To split them into 2 arrays before pass it to getJSON you need to:

1. Get JSON
2. Split data into two pieces

   ```
   var construct;

   $.getJSON('PATH_TO_config.json', function(data) {

       // splice will return first array and leaves rest in original data
       construct = data.html.splice(0, 1);

       // in the first parameter you have data.html[0] in the second
       // data.html[1..3] from the original JSON
       doSomethingWithData(construct, data.html);
   }
   ```